# Firebase Cloud Functions: Wait until request.body is valid before updating

Tags: javascript, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm having some frustration with Cloud Functions accessed via my webGL Unity app. I am getting 2 requests instead of one, and the first one is always undefined.  Therefore my database is adding 2 elements to my array which each call, one completely empty, and one valid.

Here is my cloud function, which works perfectly when tested from Unity, but not when run from my hosted site.

```
export const addSavedMission = functions.https.onRequest(
    (request, response) => {
    response.set(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "https://myunity.web.app"
    );
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    response.set("Accept", "application/json");

    // update the array data
    admin
      .firestore()
      .doc("data/missionData")
      .update({
        missions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(request.body),
      })
      .then(() => {
        response.status(200).json({ message: `Success` });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        response.status(500).json({
          message: error,
        });
      });
});
```

And here is my Unity code which calls it

```
IEnumerator PostSavedData()
{
    string data = JsonUtility.ToJson(thisMission);

    string url = $"https://us-central1-app.cloudfunctions.net/addSavedMission";
    var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

    request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://myunity.web.app");

    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    if (request.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + request.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);           
    }

}
```

When I hit this POST request from my hosted app, I log out the incoming request.rawBody, and the first is always undefined, but the second one is valid.

What am I missing here?  I'm sure there is 2 incoming requests from 1 POST.

I've tried checking to see if request.rawBody !== undefined, and only if it is not handling the firestore update but then it just never processes the 2nd valid request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first request is probably a [cors pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).  It will not contain the actual data of the request.  It's just required by the cors protocol.

Managing cors will be easier if you use the [nodejs cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) in your Cloud Function so that it automatically handles the first request.

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

export const addSavedMission = functions.https.onRequest(
    (request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        // your function code here
    })
});
```

Comment: Understood, thanks. Just for learning sake, is there a way I could ignore that first request in my cloud function without using cors?

Comment: Sure, you could try to detect it in your code, but I think it's better to let the cors module handle it correctly.

Comment: I tried and successfully detected it, but wasn't able to figure out how to ignore it. Regardless, using cors was the solution, thanks

Comment: You can't ignore it - you have to at least send a response in order to terminate the function and also tell the client that it's OK to use cors.  That's what the module will do for you.